# Dropdown is not closed when clicked outside the button in Bootstrap 5

Tags: dropdown, bootstrap-5

I have updated my site from BS4 to BS5.... all works, however, I have problems wth drop downs.

Please see this:

Well.... the drop down is opened when I click the button, but the only way to close it is by clicking inside the button again. If I click outside, dropdown is still opened.

Even when that should be the normal behaviour, I have explicitly added `data-bs-auto-close="true"` but no luck.

What is it going on here?

Note that this should be done automatically without adding some JS code. In BS4 it works correctly.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-group">
  <button id="btnFingerprints" type="button" class="btn btn-circle btn-secondary me-2 dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle-second="tooltip" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" title="Testing">
      <i class="ti-exchange-vertical"></i>
  </button>

  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" id="btnBajarHuellas">
        <i class="ti-download me-2"></i>Bajar huellas
    </button>
    
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" id="btnSubirHuellas">
        <i class="ti-upload me-2"></i>Subir huellas
    </button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
let tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle-second="tooltip"]'))
tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
</script>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine in the snippet I created. Are you loading the correct library?

Comment: @isherwood I have missed to copy it from the actual code, sorry. But have found the reason. Just when I click the drop down button, this error appeared in browser console: `Bootstrap doesn't allow more than one instance per element. Bound instance: bs.tooltip.`. This was caused because tooltips are used differently in BS5.

Comment: @isherwood I have implemented instantiation that is shown in this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/ (Example: Enable tooltips everywhere) and it works everywhere, but when I click on the drop down button, the same error occurs. I am not controlling the click event of that button so that it should be the default behaviour. What may be wrong here? Please see the modified code snippet.

Comment: You can see in the demo above that you have an instantiation problem. Bootstrap automatically sets up tooltips on elements with the data attribute, and then you're doing it again.

Comment: @isherwood which instantiation problem? Bootstrap sets automatically tooltips when data atribute name is `data-bs-toggle`. In my case, I have a dropdown which already uses that data attribute, so I created another one. Lastly, I tell you about the context. That button is created at runtime in the toolbar of a DataTable which retrieves the data using Ajax. So, that button is not present when the page loads so I need to use the DataTable event when the table is rendered. At that time, I need to attach the tooltip to the button. How can I attach it using a different data attribute?

Comment: Did you look at the console output? `Error: Bootstrap doesn't allow more than one instance per element.` Is that a problem with the demo or your code?

Comment: @isherwood the demo code snippet in the question. If the demo has the problem, or course, my code will have the problem too.